# Erro finalizando compra no magento usando PAYPAL

Tags: magento

tenho o módulo `paypal` instalado no magento, quando vou finalizar a compra e escolho o método de pagamento pelo paypal, ocorre este erro:

```
PayPal gateway recusou a solicitação. Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error).
```

Comment: Confira se o seu login e senha está correto, gere novamente o token no painel Magento. Se sua versão do **Magento** for até 1.8 baixe a versão criada para o Brasil pelo próprio **Paypal**: https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/extensao/modulo-paypal-brasil-para-magento/